# Does jquery Version v1.8.3 supports tableSorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying a lot since yesterday and looking at the following solutions but not working!

1. http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/27/make-html-table-sortable-jquery-tablesorter-plugin
2. http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: apply it and check. Also take a look at table sorter documentation

Comment: `Required: jQuery (1.2.1 or higher)` - that would be a *yes, according to the documentation it does, why would anyone on stack overflow know better than you, given that information*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Link the Following files:-

    <!-- choose a theme file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/theme.default.css">
<!-- load jQuery and tablesorter scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<!-- tablesorter widgets (optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
Use THEAD and TBODY in your HTML:-
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Due</th>
      <th>Web Site</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conway</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
use javascript function as follow:-
    $(function() {
  $("#myTable").tablesorter();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its dependency says

Dependencies

jquery >=1.2.6

check https://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/

So, it should work with jquery version 1.8.3

Ad their github says

Works with jQuery 1.2.6+ (jQuery 1.4.1+ needed with some widgets).
Works with jQuery 1.9+ ($.browser.msie was removed; needed in the original version).

check https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter.